# How to center allign Opencart Slider image

Tags: opencart

Slider images on open cart are left aligned. I have search a lot online. I couldn't find out the solution. I am using latest version of Opencart.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the actual size of the image you are uploading it would show accordingly. On the demo the images are aligned perfectly. [Link to screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhvYK.jpg)

The only other way to align items is by using the css statements "align", "margin", "float", etc.